# Mac , cronjob with command line app not working

Tags: macos, cocoa, cron

I want to delete a file from Document folder every hour. for that I uses crontab to create a cron job that executes a command line app. In the command line app, I use a terminal command to delete the file using Process().

> `eg: for the cron job :  0 * * * *  path to command line app`

from the command line app I am trying to delete a file in the document folder

The cron job executes and it calls the command line app every hour, and attempts to delete the file but fails. if we directly open the command line app the file gets deleted.

Could anyone suggest a solution for this issue.

Comment: The cronjob entry needs to specify the command line app to execute, not the path of the file to delete. And wouldn't this be simpler with a trivial shell script than writing a Swift command line app?